# Shell script fails to run on startup

Tags: linux, shell-script, startup

I want an executable program to run on startup. For this reason, I created a shell script: `/etc/init.d/server`. Then I run `chmod +x name_of_script` and `update-rc.d server defaults`.

*server (script):*

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/root/
./Server_msg
```

Server_msg prints the messages from a client. Messages are received on static IP address 192.168.1.200.

***Note**:
The connection is wireless: Static IP address 192.168.1.200 gets assigned to the device, by a script running also on startup, which loads the Wi-Fi driver's adapter.*

***The problem:***

When I added script *server* to run on startup as well, system is unable to run both scripts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you use:

```
update-rc.d server defaults
```

then `update-rc.d` will make links to start your `server` service in runlevels 2345 and to stop in  runlevels  016, all these links have sequence number `20`.

If `server` script depends on other services, e.g `networking`. So when `server` script start while its depending services haven't started yet, it will fail.

To be sure that `server` script only run when all its depending services have started, you can give `server` script higher priority:

```
update-rc.d server defaults 90
```

or add it to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Problem solved afrer running `update-rc.d server defaults 90`. Thank you!